# My Dialogflow Web service isn't detecting followup intents [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es

I have a default fallback intent that has a followup fallback intent that is attached to it (its a followup and also linked via output and input contexts). When I use the Dialogflow console to test it this feature it works well. However, when I go through my API I don't get the same effect. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong in my code?

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates http server
const { JWT } = require("google-auth-library");
const dialogflow = require("dialogflow");
const uuid = require("uuid");
const token = "token"; // type here your verification token
const result = "";

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // check if verification token is correct
  if (req.query.token !== token) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }

  // return challenge
  return res.end(req.query.challenge);
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // check if verification token is correct
  if (req.query.token !== token) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }

  // print request body
  console.log(req.body);
  //var request = req;
  //console.log(req.body.result.parameters.testing);
  console.log(req.body.result.resolvedQuery);
  runSample();

  /**
   * Send a query to the dialogflow agent, and return the query result.
   * @param {string} projectId The project to be used
   */
  async function runSample(projectId = "projectid") {
    // A unique identifier for the given session
    const sessionId = uuid.v4();

    // Create a new session
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
          text: req.body.result.resolvedQuery,
          // The language used by the client (en-US)
          languageCode: "en-US"
        }
      }
    };

    // Send request and log result
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    console.log("Detected intent");
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
    if (result.intent) {
      console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
      //first not matched user query
      if (result.intent.displayName === 'Default Fallback Intent')
        {
          result.fulfillmentText = 'Sorry, can you rephase your question?';
          //result.fulfillmentText = 'Sorry, I am unable to answer your question';
        }
      if (result.intent.displayName === 'Default Fallback Intent - fallback')
        {
          //result.fulfillmentText = 'Sorry, can you rephase your question?';
          result.fulfillmentText = 'Sorry, I am unable to answer your question';
        } 
      // return a text response
      const data = {
        responses: [
          {
            type: "text",
            elements: [result.fulfillmentText]
          }
        ]
      };
      // return a text response
      res.json(data);
    } else {
      console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
    }
  }
});

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: i am worried you are creating new session id in each request

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya hmm makes sense, how then to keep the same session and not have it persistent via the API?

Comment: you can authorisation tokens to identify your unique users

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are either looking at the Context that is sent back as part of `result`, nor sending any Context in your call to `sessionClient.detectIntent(request);`. Dialogflow only maintains state in Contexts, in the same way a web server might maintain state through Cookies, so it does not know that an Output Context was set unless you send it as an Input Context the next round.

Because of this, every Fallback ends up being treated as the "Default Fallback Intent".

Comment: But in the console the output context is set once the default fallback intent is activated.